# How to regex a string of length 15 in a specific pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have to regex a string whose format should be like

```
Position  Format
1st       Numeric
2nd       Numeric
3rd       Alphabet
4th       Alphabet
5th       Alphabet
6th       Alphabet
7th       Alphabet
8th       Numeric
9th       Numeric
10th      Numeric
11th      Numeric
12th      Alphabet
13th      AlphaNumeric
14th      AlphaNumeric
15th      AlphaNumeric
```

then finally have to match if the regex is valid

```
Match match = Regex.Match( inputString, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );

if ( inputString != string.Empty && match.Success )
{
     // Condition
}
```

I am actually stuck. I am using c# .Looping through the characters an checking the conditions. But this does not look like an ideal solution .
Please assist using Regex/C#

Comment: See https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex

Comment: Try `@"^[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$"`

Comment: Quickly try out your regex with http://regexr.com/

Comment: `\d{2}[A-Za-z]{5}\d{4}[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d]{3}`

Comment: What is the meaning of "Alphabet" exactly? Does it contain accented characters?

Comment: Please let know if the pattern must be Unicode aware. Please also let know if the string should pass if there is a trailing newline in the input string.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This regex could be expressed as follows

```
\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{5}\d{4}[a-zA-Z][\da-zA-Z]{3}
```

Comment: You used both \d and 0-9 for numeric; probably best to be consistent.

Comment: @Polyfun so I did, well spotted

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to match the whole string that matches the pattern you defined.

Use

```
var isValid = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\A[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\z");
```

If you need to make it Unicode aware, replace all `[0-9]` with `\d` and all `[a-zA-Z]` with `\p{L}`.

**Details**:

- `\A` - start of string
- `[0-9]{2}` - 2 digits
- `[a-zA-Z]{5}` - 5 letters
- `[0-9]{4}` - 4 digits
- `[a-zA-Z]` -  a letter
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}` - 3 alphanumeric symbols (Unicode aware - `[\p{L}\p{N}]`)
- `\z` - the very end of string. If a newline (LF) char follows it and is the last char in the string, the match will fail.

Comment: Also, see [the regex demo on RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cA%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%5ba-zA-Z%5d%7b5%7d%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d%5ba-zA-Z%5d%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%7b3%7d%5cz&i=12abcde3456f0a1).